# How to store '\0' in a char array

Tags: c, string, printf

Is it possible to store the char `'\0'` inside a char array and then store different characters after? For example

```
char* tmp = "My\0name\0is\0\0";
```

I was taught that is actually called a string list in C, but when I tried to print the above (using `printf("%s\n", tmp)`), it only printed

> "My".

Comment: how do you know it only saved `My`? it probably saved the entire sequence, but the printing functions stop after "seeing" the null character `\0`

Comment: True, edited. So how can I print it all?

Comment: You shoud post the code you used to print `tmp` -- the problem is whith that code and not with the ability of storing \0 in a char array

Comment: `printf(%s\n", tmp);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is surely possible, however, furthermore, you cannot use that array as *string* and get the content stored after the `'\0'`.

By definition, a *string* is a `char` array, **terminated by** the null character, `'\0'`. All string related function will stop at the terminating null byte (for example, an argument, containing a `'\0'` in between the actual contents, passed to format specifier`%s` in `printf()`).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.1.1, *Definitions of terms*

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters **terminated by and including the first null
>   character.** [...]

However, for byte-by-byte processing, you're good to go as long as you stay within the allocated memory region.

Comment: So how can I print the whole thing?

Comment: @UFCInsider iterate over the array, get every element and print them , possible using `%c`. Remember to stay within array limits though.

Comment: @UFCInsider because of syntax error in `if (*(p + i) == '\0'))`.

Comment: Thanks... I will maybe ask this in a different question

Comment: @UFCInsider Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is with the function you are using to print `tmp`.  Functions like printf will assume that the string is null terminated, so it will stop when it sees the first \0

If you try the following code you will see more of the value in `tmp`

```
int main(int c,char** a){
    char* tmp = "My\0name\0is\0\0";
    write(1,tmp,12);
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. What is wrong with how I print?

Comment: @UFCInsider -- That is really a new question and no longer `How to store '\0' in a char array` -- create a new question